# How to insert a full width div inside a container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a few divs inside a 900px width container.

I need one of these divs to go full browser width. How is this possible using Bootstrap?

Update:

Fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/vhqRQRPeBH

When clicking on the Filter Group, it filter options in a row bellow. I need this row grey background to be full browser width, and the buttons to stay inside the container like in this picture example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oefeW.jpg

This in order for the row with the filter options to show bellow each respective Filter Group when they are stacked in a smaller screen.

Comment: Your fiddle link returns an error.

Comment: There was some probelm with bootply, but it's working now.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without JavaScript. If you want CSS-only, you would have to wrap each row with a wrapper + `.container`, not all of them in a single `.container`.

Answer (score 2):

*You can just split your page...*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/PIWtapBtS1

**HTML** :

```
  <div class="container">                        <!-- IN CONTAINER -->
      <div class="row bleu">
        <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
      </div> 
  </div>                                        <!-- END IN CONTAINER -->
  <div class="col-md-12 rouge">                 <!-- FULL WIDTH -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
        </div>
  </div>                                        <!-- END FULL WIDTH -->
  <div class="container">                       <!-- IN CONTAINER -->
      <div class="row vert">
        <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
      </div>
  </div>                                        <!-- END IN CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: I just made an update explaining better what I need to achieve.

Comment: it's is not the same thing. In your example, when it is loaded into a smaller screen and the columns get stacked, the "rouge" shows bellow the second box (column), when it should show bellow the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need this for styling purposes. `.container` is supposed to be used as a content wrapper, so you should mark it up like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- your content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The other way around won't work.

Then in CSS you style the `.header`:

```
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Now you got a full-width background.

If you need your content to go full-width too, you can use `.container-fluid` instead:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- your content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you should describe your situation better.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I just made an update to my post to explain better what I need.